# Is it possible to upgrade my MacBook Pro RAM and Hard Drive?

Tags: macbook-pro, upgrade, memory, hardware-recommendation

I bought Macbook Pro 15 inch laptop last year with 4 GB RAM and 300 GB Hard disk, Now I feel like upgrading its RAM to 8 GB and 1 TB hard disk. I want to know is it possible to do that or not.

```
My system configuration is as follows:
    Hardware Overview:
      Model Name:   MacBook Pro
      Model Identifier: MacBookPro5,1
      Processor Name:   Intel Core 2 Duo
      Processor Speed:  2.66 GHz
      Number Of Processors: 1
      Total Number Of Cores:    2
      L2 Cache: 6 MB
      Memory:   4 GB
      Bus Speed:    1.07 GHz
      Boot ROM Version: MBP51.007E.B05
      SMC Version (system): 1.41f2
      Serial Number (system):   W89123XF71A
      Hardware UUID:    CF78C5AA-188D-538A-8250-F21B474DEF9E
      Sudden Motion Sensor:
      State:    Enabled

Memory Slots:
  ECC:  Disabled
BANK 0/DIMM0:
  Size: 2 GB
  Type: DDR3
  Speed:    1067 MHz
  Status:   OK
  Manufacturer: 0x80CE
  Part Number:  0x4D34373142353637334448312D4346382020
  Serial Number:    0x446323C2

BANK 0/DIMM1:

  Size: 2 GB
  Type: DDR3
  Speed:    1067 MHz
  Status:   OK
  Manufacturer: 0x80CE
  Part Number:  0x4D34373142353637334448312D4346382020
  Serial Number:    0x44632496
```

By looking up the above config, what is the max amount of RAM and hard drive can I upgrade to?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding upgrades, as per [this answer to a related question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24851/how-to-determine-how-much-ram-i-can-put-in-my-mac-pro/24860#24860), OWC is a reliable resource. [Here are their pages on memory](http://eshop.macsales.com/shop/memory/Apple_MacBook_MacBook_Pro/Upgrade) - it looks like 16 GB (2 x 8GB modules) will be your max RAM.

Similarly, [here's info on hard-drive upgrades](http://eshop.macsales.com/shop/memory/Apple_MacBook_MacBook_Pro/Upgrade/DDR3_1333MHz_SDRAM). It looks like 1TB is going to be your maximum, though as far as I know that's merely a limitation to what sizes are available in the 2.5-inch form factor that the MacBook Pro (and almost every other laptop in existence) uses. If and when larger 2.5-inch drives are released, an MBP should be able to use one.